# Finding nearest neighbor using 1D index for 3D coordinates

Tags: mysql

Many others have used the method of indexing 3D coordinates with a 1D index using the function:

> 1D_index = f(x,y,z) = x + (max_width)*y + (max_width)(max_height)*z,

or a variation of this function.

My question is: Is there an algorithm that can find the 1D_index of the nearest neighbor (y) of a specified coordinate (x) by only using the 1D_index of x?

Or am I much better off forgetting this approach and switching to an R-tree or kd-tree?